# JS Live Search Filter Uncaught in promise error

Tags: javascript, json

I'm working through a live search bar with javaScript and JSON and am getting this error and I can't figure it out:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
    at outputHtml (main.js:35)
    at searchStates (main.js:19)
```

I have no idea why. Any help? Code:

```
const matchList = document.getElementById("matchList");

//search and filter data
const searchStates = async (searchText) => {
  const res = await fetch("../data/states.json");
  const states = await res.json();

  //find input matches
  let matches = states.filter((state) => {
    const regex = new RegExp(`^${searchText}`, "gi");
    return state.name.match(regex) || state.abbr.match(regex);
  });

  if (searchText.length === 0) {
    matches = [];
  }

  outputHtml(matches);
};

//show filtered results
const outputHtml = matches => {
  if (matches.length > 0) {
    const html = matches
      .map(
        match => `
        <div class="card card-body mb-1">
            <h4>${match.name} (${match.abbr}) <span class="text-primary">${match.capital}</span></h4>
            <small>Lat: ${match.lat} / Long: ${match.long}</small>
        </div>
        `
      )
      .join("");
    matchList.innerHTML = html;
  }
};

search.addEventListener("input", () => searchStates(search.value));
```

line 19 is the `outputHtml(matches);`  and line 35 is  `matchList.innerHTML = html;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`matchList` is undefined please add condition to check it

```
if (matchList && matches.length > 0)
```

Or

```
matchList.innerHTML = html;
```

replace with

```
document.getElementById("matchList").innerHTML = html;
```

Comment: I had the id in html set to "match-list" not "matchList". I'm an idiot lol. Thanks for the help

Comment: I'm now getting this error:Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined
    at main.js:12
    at Array.filter (<anonymous>)
    at searchStates (main.js:10)

Comment: @MarcelPenney please update your question with files and details

Comment: @MarcelPenney please debug your `searchStates` function its issue with your `response` as `res`

Comment: How would I debug it? It's weird it worked fine before and I haven't changed anything

Comment: @MarcelPenney please condole log `states` and check what is result